# Why does this query causes sequential scan?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm very new to PostgreSQL, forgive me if something obvious is not clear for me. I have a database with ~450 million rows distributed across 6 tables (every table has primary key). When I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM "Payments" AS p
JOIN "PaymentOrders" AS po ON po."Id" = p."PaymentOrderId"
WHERE po."Id" = 1000
```

po."Id" is primary key. I just VACUUM ANALYZED whole database. You can see EXPLAIN ANALYZE details **[here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/CrrS)**. PaymentOrders table contains 40 million rows, while Payments contains 350 million rows. 
I'm running x64 PostgreSQL 9.2 on Windows 8 machine, I5 CPU (4 cores 3.3GHz), 8GB of RAM.
Also you can see my postgresql.conf file [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3055964/postgresql.conf).

Anyone has any idea why this query causes a sequential scan on Payments table? Am I doing something wrong or PostgreSQL has some serious flaws?
I started to seriously doubt in PostgreSQL query planner...

Comment: Version, explain analyze, query text ... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you index both sides of the FOREIGN KEY relation? In particular, is there an index on `Payments.PaymentOrderID`?

Comment: No I didn't because only PaymentOrder.Id is contained in where clause. I'll try indexing second side and let you know the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are po."Id" = p."PaymentOrderId" the same type?  They need to match for the planner to use an index to join on them.